# Creating a .tgz with windows?

Tags: compression

Sorry, just a quick question before I submit an assignment online. I just followed this guide -

http://www.ehow.com/how_6104990_create-_tgz-file-windows.html

to make a .tgz file from one of my folder. I then renamed the file created from .tar.gz to a .tgz.

I was just wondering would this have the exact same result as the instructions my professor gave us for submission :

"Run the command ‘tar cvfz Lab-2.tgz Lab-2’ from your working directory. The
option ‘v’ makes tar very chatty: it should tell you exactly what is going into the .tgz
archive. Make sure you check the tar output before submitting your archive."

Thank you very much, and sorry for the silly question...I just don't want to be losing marks because of silly things like this ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just FYI: If any of the files have been modified locally then the silly windows line-endings may have been introduced (accidentally).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, 7-Zip will produce gzipped tar files the same as the Linux tar command.

You can open the file you created in 7-Zip and look at the files in it to verify that it contains what you wanted.

But I would recommend learning Linux if you are taking a class where it is recommended.  If nothing else, you can install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and use the tar command from there.

Answer (score 3):

The file contents are the same. Both tar.gz and .tgz represent the same compressed archive. you can run either

```
tar cvfz Lab-2.tgz Lab-2
```

or

```
tar cvfz Lab-2.tar.gz Lab-2
```

if you did a diff they would be the same.

Comment: or you could even do tar cvfz Lab-2.tar.IlikeTurtles Lab-2, the contents will always be identical.

Answer (score 2):

.tgz is equivalent to .tar.gz

You can confirm that the tarball is good by un-gzipping it and then untarring it.